# How to save specific rows in a matrix to a new matrix?

Tags: python, loops, matrix, error-handling

I'm new to python/ programming. I'm trying to make a small function that loops through each row in an x-by-3 matrix have errors in them. I want to save all the rows **without** errors in a new x-by-3 matrix. For example, the input could be:

```
[[50.     0.096  2.   ]
 [15.     0.517  3.   ]
 [35.     1.086  4.   ]
 [40.     0.934  2.   ]
 [35.     0.109  1.   ]]
```

My code:

```
def function(f5):
    for i in range(f5.shape[0]):
        if f5[i,0] < 10:
            print("error1")
        elif f5[i,0] > 60: 
            print("error2")
        elif f5[i, 1] < 0:
            print("error3")
        elif (f5[i, 2] != 1) and (f5[i, 2] != 2) and (f5[i, 2] != 3) and (f5[i, 2] != 4):
            print("error4")
        else:
            #I'm not sure how to save the rows that pass these tests in a 
             new matrix.
```

I would REALLY appreciate any help.